# LDAP SearchFilter CN Name from Variable defined from user input

Tags: python, ldap

I am trying to create a variable from a user input. Then have the search filter use that variable.

The following is a bit of code from my python script that retrieves CN Name and email from AD Directory succesfully when the name is hard coded in "John Doe".

```
retrieveAttributes = ["name"] and ["mail"]
searchFilter = "(&(name=John Doe)" \
               "(!(objectClass=computer))" \
               "(&(objectClass=person)))"
```

I was able to get this far, by creating the user input variable called "adname", but not sure how to make the SearchFilter name use the variable "adname":

```
adname = raw_input("Search CN Name:")
 print adname
 retrieveAttributes = ["name"] and ["mail"]
 searchFilter = "(&(name = adname)" \
           "(!(objectClass=computer))" \
           "(&(objectClass=person)))"
```

Any insights are much appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare the search string as a *string variable*:

First step - instead of

```
searchFilter = "(&(name=John Doe)" \
               "(!(objectClass=computer))" \
               "(&(objectClass=person)))"
```

you may use

```
search       = "(&(name=John Doe)" \
               "(!(objectClass=computer))" \
               "(&(objectClass=person)))"

searchFilter = search
```

Now it is no problem to prepare search for including the name from your input:

```
search       = "(&(name={})" \
               "(!(objectClass=computer))" \
               "(&(objectClass=person)))"  \
               .format(adname)           # replaces {} with the content of adname
```

and using the same search filter:

```
searchFilter = search
```

Comment: now i see the logic behind :-) However i get the following error:

"(!(objectClass=computer))" \
                                           ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. It doesnt like the last double quotation

Comment: Oh, there remains unbalanced parenthesis! I edited my answer so the *whole* search string is assigned to a string variable - and I tested it, so it now works.